# how to create Plugin for Kibana 5.6.3

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5

I want to create a plugin for kibana version 5.6.3,due to this i follow the link "https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing-code",the github provider the source code of the latest version kibana 7.0.0 https://github.com/elastic/kibana .but i need the kibana version 5.6.3 to create a plugin, where I get the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link that you provide will not help you develop plugin, look at the next video [tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/creating-custom-kibana-visualizations)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an SAO generater: https://github.com/elastic/template-kibana-plugin/

The video tutorial provided by Lax was created a couple weeks ago, and is up-to-date.